# React Native 100% de memória

Tags: react-native

Estou utilizando o emulador do *Android Studio* para visualizar um *app* desenvolvido em *React Nativ*e, assim que rodo o comando '`start`' do *React Native* no *prompt*, a aplicação começa consumir memória infinitamente até *crashar* o PC, comecei a utilizar o *React Native* ontem e não consegui resolver esse problema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Desisti de usar React Native no Windows, no linux é muito mais rápido.

Comment: Sem contexto, qualquer resposta é puramente achismo. Utilizo diariamente o Android Studio para desenvolvimento com React Native e Flutter, sem problemas. Tem alguma informação a mais que possa incluir na pergunta?

Comment: Como comecei ontem a aprender React Native, minha percepção de problemas ainda é muito baixa, mas, basicamente, ao iniciar a aplicação o consumo de memória que a mesma consome não para de subir, apesar da aplicação funcionar normalmente.

Comment: @GabrielZendine Estava passando pelos mesmos probemas! A solução mais plausivel é voce migrar para o  Linux , estou usando o Ubuntu agora e não tive mais problemas com gerenciamento de  memoria  e disco 100%. Meu windows travava umas 20 ou 30 vezes no dia! Mudei para o Linux e isso não é mais problema.(Tenho um Dual boot com linux e windows no meu humilde notebook corei5 e 8G de RAM e predendo colocar um hd ssd  futuramente.) Claro se a pessoa tem um SUPER COMPUTADOR não importa qual o seu SO, mas acho que esse não é o nosso caso....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A princípio você poderia usar o app [expo](https://expo.io/) para testar o seu código diretamente no seu dispositivo android, e codificar no Windows, sem precisar usar o Android Studio.

Para quem está começando o expo é uma boa solução, entretanto para recursos mais avançados ele tem algumas limitações.

Com ele você cria seu app no seu editor preferido e quando salvar elas já são atualizadas no seu dispositivo.

Você tambem pode criar uma conta no expo e aprender sobre react editando apps direto no browser e rodando no seu smartphone :).

Tudo isso sem estouro de memoria e disco 100%.

Depois que aprender o react-native e for partir para recursos mais avançados. Mude de sistema operacional como eu fiz(Para o Linux [Ubuntu]) e não me arrependo.Ai você vai poder usar os emuladores do android studio sem tantos gargalos de memória e usos excessivos do disco.

Veja aqui como [instalar o expo](https://expo.io/learn).

Esse [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bTfaLDDLCqQ) do youtube tem um breve tutorial.